# Blob skipping first column while generating csv file

Tags: javascript, blob

I am trying to generate a CSV file using blob class. The first row is working fine but the rest of the rows are skipping the first column

```js
var ExcelIndex = ['"user_name","user_hash","authenticate_id","first_name","last_name","description","department","phone_home","phone_mobile","phone_work","phone_other","phone_fax","address_street","address_city","address_state","address_country","address_postalcode","Errors"'];
var dataInSingleStringArray = new Array();
dataInSingleStringArray.push(ExcelIndex[0], "\n");
var ExcelInde = ['"user_name","user_hash","authenticate_id","first_name","last_name","description","department","phone_home","phone_mobile","phone_work","phone_other","phone_fax","address_street","address_city","address_state","address_country","address_postalcode","Errors"'];
// var dataInSingleStringArray = new Array();
dataInSingleStringArray.push(ExcelInde[0], "\n");

window.URL = window.webkitURL || window.URL;
var contentType = 'text/csv';
var csvFile = new Blob([dataInSingleStringArray], {type: contentType});
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.setAttribute("style", "margin-left: 700px;font-size: 2em;")
a.download = 'failed_data.csv';
a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(csvFile);
a.textContent = 'Download File';
document.getElementById('link').appendChild(a);
```

```html
<div id="link"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding "\n" each time you add data to your array, Add data to your array then join it with "\n"

```js
      var ExcelIndex = ['"user_name","user_hash","authenticate_id","first_name","last_name","description","department","phone_home","phone_mobile","phone_work","phone_other","phone_fax","address_street","address_city","address_state","address_country","address_postalcode","Errors"'];
      var dataInSingleStringArray = new Array();

      dataInSingleStringArray.push(ExcelIndex[0]);

      var ExcelInde = ['"user_name","user_hash","authenticate_id","first_name","last_name","description","department","phone_home","phone_mobile","phone_work","phone_other","phone_fax","address_street","address_city","address_state","address_country","address_postalcode","Errors"'];
      // var dataInSingleStringArray = new Array();

      dataInSingleStringArray.push(ExcelInde[0]);
      //console.log(dataInSingleStringArray);
      //console.log(dataInSingleStringArray.join("\r\n"));


      window.URL = window.webkitURL || window.URL;
      var contentType = 'text/csv';
      var csvFile = new Blob([dataInSingleStringArray.join("\n")], {type: contentType});
      var a = document.createElement('a');
      a.setAttribute("style", "margin-left: 700px;font-size: 2em;")
      a.download = 'failed_data.csv';

      a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(csvFile);
      a.textContent = 'Download File';
      document.getElementById('link').appendChild(a);
```

```html
<div id="link"></div>
```

Comment: Why we need to add \n while making object of blob class not in every array